# Replacing Character at Index in Swift

Tags: swift, string

I'm currently making a hangman game in Swift.

The game randomly generates a word, which the user has to guess.

The user enters guesses a single letter at a time. If the guess is correct, then that letter should be revealed in the nulled out string.

For example if the word is APPLE, the string would start as:

_ _ _ _ _.

If the user guesses the letter A, the string would then appear to the user 
as:

A _ _ _ _.

The way I have this implemented is there are two string variables, stringToGuess, and stringToDisplay. stringToGuess is the full word (APPLE), and string to display is the word with underscores (A _ _ _ _).

So far, I have this code written. It doesn't compile because the array operator [] is read-only on the string.

What is the best way to replace a character at an index?

```swift
        let buttonCharacter = sender.currentTitle!

        if(wordToGuess.contains(buttonCharacter)) {
            for(i, character) in wordToGuess.enumerated() {
                if(buttonCharacter.first == character) {
                    wordToDisplay[i] = character
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace anything but the guessed characters only if they are correct. So look at this:

```
var wordToGuess = "Apple"

let selectedCharacters = ["p", "e"]

let wordToDisplay = wordToGuess.map { selectedCharacters.contains(String($0)) ? String($0) : "_" } .joined()

print(wordToDisplay)
```

each time user selects a new character, you should add it to the `selectedCharacters` and do the `map` again.

Comment: You can avoid `String($0)` by mapping over the characters itself: `let wordToDisplay = String(wordToGuess.map { selectedCharacters.contains($0) ? $0 : "_" })`. You'd need to declare `selectedCharacters` as an array of characters, though, for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the indices of your stringToGuess that contains the guessed character and use those indices to replace the stringToDisplay corresponding characters:

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    @discardableResult
    mutating func replaceOccurrences<S: StringProtocol>(of character: Character, in string: S) -> Bool {
        precondition(count == string.count)
        var found = false
        string.indices.filter {
            string[$0] == character
        }.forEach {
            found = true
            replaceSubrange($0...$0, with: CollectionOfOne(character))
        }
        return found
    }
}
```

---

**Playground testing:**

```
let stringToGuess = "APPLE"
var stringToDisplay = String(repeating: "_", count: stringToGuess.count)
```

---

```
var guess: Character = "A"
if stringToDisplay.replaceOccurrences(of: guess, in: stringToGuess) {
    print("Hangman:", stringToDisplay)   // "Hangman: A____\n"
} else {
    print("Character \(guess) not found on \(stringToGuess)")
}
```

---

```
guess = "E"
if stringToDisplay.replaceOccurrences(of: guess, in: stringToGuess) {
    print("Hangman:", stringToDisplay)   // "Hangman: A___E\n"
} else {
    print("Character \(guess) not found on \(stringToGuess)")
}
```

---

```
guess = "I"
if stringToDisplay.replaceOccurrences(of: guess, in: stringToGuess) {
    print("Hangman:", stringToDisplay)   // "Hangman: A___E\n"
} else {
    print("Character \(guess) not found on \(stringToGuess)")
}
```

---

```
guess = "P"
if stringToDisplay.replaceOccurrences(of: guess, in: stringToGuess) {
    print("Hangman:", stringToDisplay)   // "Hangman: APP_E\n"
} else {
    print("Character \(guess) not found on \(stringToGuess)")
}
```

---

```
guess = "L"
if stringToDisplay.replaceOccurrences(of: guess, in: stringToGuess) {
    print("Hangman:", stringToDisplay)   // "Hangman: APPLE\n""""
} else {
    print("Character \(guess) not found on \(stringToGuess)")
}
```

This will print

> Hangman: A____
>
> Hangman: A___E
>
> Character I not found on APPLE
>
> Hangman: APP_E
>
> Hangman: APPLE

Answer (score 0):

Since a `String` is a collection of characters, you can use `map` to convert the characters either to the original value, or to "_" if that character was not yet typed:

```swift
func hangman(search: String, typedCharacters: Set<Character>) -> String {
    return String(search.map { typedCharacters.contains($0) ? $0 : "_" })
}
```

Every time the user types a new letter, you only need to add it to the set of characters:

```swift
let search = "APPLE"
var typedCharacters = Set<Character>()

typedCharacters.insert("A")
print(hangman(search: search, typedCharacters: typedCharacters)) // A _ _ _ _

typedCharacters.insert("L")
print(hangman(search: search, typedCharacters: typedCharacters)) // A _ _ L _

typedCharacters.insert("O")
print(hangman(search: search, typedCharacters: typedCharacters)) // A _ _ L _
```